I can not build gradle project but no idea why
I'm a first learner of Java and Spring boot.
I'm following a easy level handbook, but my intelliJ return same error message repeatly.
I'm trying to fix this but only failed until now. So I asking help here.
Leaving build.gradle code and the error message.
What I want is just Hint about what was wrong, and how to fix.
What I typed in build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    }  
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()   
    }

        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")  
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot' 
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')  
        testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')  
    }

And the error message back from IntelliJ:
Build file 'PATHofMYPROJECT\build.gradle' line: 17

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MYPROJECT'.
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.publish.ArchivePublishArtifact.<init>(Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/AbstractArchiveTask;)V

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Thank you
(What I was expecting for, was just a build process of Gradle project without problem)

This is a really old build script that will not work with newer versions of Gradle. Even JCenter no longer exists. If you are trying to learn Java (or Gradle or Spring), I recommend finding a newer guide.

Thank you very much.
(I know JCenter is gone as IntelliJ shown it as gray letters, but not ignored them with no serious reason)
This book is established at 2020 so I agree it is old, But didn't forecast fail of build until error message came back...


I'm also interested in newer guides. Could you please recommend a book title? I borrowed this book from the library, and I'm wondering how to find a good guide.



So, the cause of the build failure is that ‘the version of Gradle has now changed’ and that the build script itself (its syntax) is invalid?

(That build script doesn't work now, but it would have worked in 2020. I was curious about the part of the script's code that caused it, and what and how to fix it to make that build script work.)

I suggest you use the spring initializr to setup a project (https://start.spring.io/)
You can select Gradle/Maven and the Spring Boot version you are targetting.

I know it, Thank you so much
